# Conjugation of Unitary Matrices in Quantum Channel

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-operation

A quantum channel is given in the form $U(\rho)=\sum_{j}p_jK_j\rho K_j^\dagger$. I have read in another thread that a quantum channel is the generalized version of a quantum gate (represented by a unitary oprator $G$, such that passing a state $|\psi\rangle$ through the gate is the same as multiplying $G$ with $|\psi\rangle$).

I think I understand how a quantum gate works; it's a simply matrix multiplication by a unitary operator with the quantum state. My question is, why does the form for quantum channel contain conjugation by the Kraus operators $K_j$? If a quantum channel is the generalization of a quantum gate, why do they have different forms? And is there any intuition as to why conjugation by the $K_j$ may be present in the equation for a quantum channel $U$?

One reason I suspect this is the case is that quantum channels operate on density operators, not linear quantum states, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: If you want to recover $|\psi\rangle \mapsto U |\psi\rangle$ then you need $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| \mapsto U |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|U^\dagger$